# Building a list inside a list in python

Tags: python, list

I have been trying to add some data in a python list. I am actually going to store the data as a list inside a list. Now, the data is not coming index-wise.

To explain that lets say I have a list of lists 'a'. Now I have data for `a[2]` before `a[1]`. And both `a[1]` and `a[2]` are lists themselves. Now, obviously I can't assign anything to `a[2]` before assigning `a[1]`. And I don't know how much lists would be there. I mean, this is supposed to be dynamic.

Any solution to this, so that I can successfully build the list?

Comment: use dictionary . suits well for your requirement

Comment: Your example is not very clear to me. Can you please elaborate more on your example?

Comment: OKay, the idea is that I have an empty list, that I am going to populate. And as said in the example I have data for a[1] before a[0]. Now, I cant assign a[1] before a[0]. By reading the answers I guess I am going with dictionaries!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could append empty lists until you have enough to access the index you have data for:

```
while len(outerlist) <= idx:
    outerlist.append([])
```

However, you may want to use a dictionary instead, letting you implement a *sparse* object instead. A [`collections.defaultdict()` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is especially useful here:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)

data[2].append(3)
data[5].append(42)
```

`data` now has keys `2` and `5`, each a list with one element. No entries for `0`, `1`, `3`, or `4` exist yet.

Comment: @DSM: ick, my inverted logic circuits are out of caffeine.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, to fill empty list with definite amount of lists.
Here is my way out
I made a "board" 6x6 filled with O, just for instant:

```
board = []    
for i in range(6): # create a list with nested lists
    board.append([])
    for n in range(6):
        board[i].append("O") # fills nested lists with data
```

Result:

```
[['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], 
 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this solution solves your problem.

Create the secondary list(inside_list) local to the for loop

```
    outside_list=[]
    for i in range(0,5):
        inside_list=[]
        inside_list.append(i)
        inside_list.append(i+1)
        outside_list.append(inside_list)

       #you can access any inside_list from the outside_list and append     
        outside_list[1].append(100)
        print(outside_list)
```

Output:

> ```
> [[0, 1], [1, 2, 100], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]]
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it, there is no problem appending an element.

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3], [10,20,30], [100,200,300]]
>>> a[2].append(400)
 [[1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30], [100, 200, 300, 400]]
>>> a[1].append(40)
 [[1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30, 40], [100, 200, 300, 400]]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I guess it works only for lists that already have elements. I want to start from an empty list. I dont think it's possible to do this in an empty list.

Comment: Yes, exactly, in that case you could add empty lists or use a dictionary instead as other answers suggest

Comment: Yeah, I guess dictionary would be better option to go with. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can use the first item in the list as an index and then make use of it for adding the right value to it at runtime using the list.

```
def unclean_(index, val, unclean=None):
   is_added = False
   if unclean is None:
       unclean = []
   length = len(unclean)
   if length == 0:
       unclean.append([index, val])
   else:
       for x in range(length):
            if unclean[x][0] == index:
                unclean[x].append(val)
                is_added = True
       if not is_added:
            unclean.append([index, val])

def terminate_even(x):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        raise Exception("Its even number")

def terminate_odd(x):
    if x % 2 != 0:
        raise Exception("Its odd number")

def fun():
    unclean = []
    for x in range(10):
       try:
            terminate_even(x)
       except:
            unclean_("terminate_even", x, unclean)

    for x in range(10):
       try:
            terminate_odd(x)
       except:
            unclean_("terminate_odd", x, unclean)

    for y in unclean:
        print y

 def main():
    fun()

 if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

 Output:
 -------
     ['terminate_even', 0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
     ['terminate_odd', 1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Simply

I am gonna make it as simple as it gets, No need for fancy modules,

Just make an empty list in the start of the file, and then append that empty list whenever you need it like,

## Example

Until the Function get_data give a certain output add empty lists within a list.

```
#/usr/bin/python3
#coding:utf-8
empty_list = []
r = ''
def get_data():
    # does something here and gives the output
    return output
imp_list = []
while r == %something%:
    r = get_data()
    imp_list.append(empty_list)
```

Comment: Because you're appending `empty_list` at each iteration, you're actually creating a structure where all the elements of `imp_list` are aliases of each other. E.g., if you do `imp_list[1].append(4)`, you will find that `imp_list[0]` now also has that extra element. So, instead, you should do `imp_list.append([])` and make each element of `imp_list` independent.