# How would I split a list of tuples into chunks

Tags: python, tuples, chunks

I have a list that looks something like this:
weather_history=((year,month,day),precip,tmin,tmax)

I need to split it into one-year chunks where each chunk is a list with one years worth of data
please help!

```
    all_years_data: List[Weather_List] = []
    
    for line,p,n,x in weather_history:
            
        year=line[0]
        day=line[2]
        month=line[1]
        precip=p
        tmin=n
        tmax=x

        if year not in all_years_data:
            all_years_data.append(year)
```

this is my code so far. I've tried many different things to get all of each years worth of data into one list but can't figure it out

Comment: you need something like [ [year,day,month,tmin,tmax],[ [year,day,month,tmin,tmax] ] ? List inside list ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980396/building-a-list-inside-a-list-in-python

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```py
A = [((1,2,3),4,5,6), ((10,20,30),40,50,60), ((100,200,300),400,500,600)]

B = [i[0][0] for i in A]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is like this:

```
weather_history = ((2020,6,12),30,10,40)
```

you can use `weather_history` index without `for` statement :

```
year = weather_history[0][0]
day = weather_history[0][1]
month = weather_history[0][2]
precip = weather_history[1]
tmin = weather_history[2]
tmax = weather_history[3]
if year not in all_years_data:
    all_years_data.append(year)
```

---

But if your data is like this:

```
weather_history = [((2020,6,12),30,10,40),((2021,6,12),30,10,40),((2022,6,12),30,10,40)]
```

you should loop `weather_history` data with `for` statement :

```
for line in weather_history:
  year = line[0][0]
  day = line[0][1]
  month = line[0][2]
  precip = line[1]
  tmin = line[2]
  tmax = line[3]
  if year not in all_years_data:
      all_years_data.append(year)
```

---